# adding up items in a list error with PYTHON

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to add up all the items in  the list, list:

```
def sum_items(list):
    k = 0
    for i in range(len(list)):
        k = k + list[i]
    return k



list = [2,3,4,5]
```

***this is an example, I want to do it for n items in list***

print(k)

```
I got an error: File "xxx.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(k)
NameError: name 'k' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Where are you even calling the function?

Comment: I don't believe they are

Answer (score 0):

You need pass the list to the `sum_items` function. And don't use `list` as a variable name.

```
def sum_items(lis):
    k = 0
    for i in range(len(lis)):
        k = k + lis[i]
    return k

print(sum_items([2,3,4,5]))
```

or

```
lis = [2,3,4,5] 
print(sum_items(lis))
```

Comment: Having said not to use `list`, you then go and use `l`.  PEP008:  *Never use the characters 'l' (lowercase letter el), 'O' (uppercase letter oh), or 'I' (uppercase letter eye) as single character variable names.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign something to `k` first.

```
k = sum_items(list)
print (k)
```

or

```
print (sum_items(list))
```

If you are looking at summing the first "n" items in list, you could use slicing:

```
def sum_items(n, yourList):
    k = sum(yourList[:n])
    return k
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Python actually has an inbuilt function to get the sum of all the numbers in a list. `sum([1, 2, 3])` will return `6`

However, the problem with your code is that you are only defining k within a function. A function is basically a bunch of steps to be performed on some unknown value. You need to call the function on the value like this

```
k = sum_items([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

OUTSIDE AND UNDERNEATH THE FUNCTION

Example:

```
def add(n):
    return n+1

k = add(4)
print(k)
```

That is the only problem.

What you need to do is something like this

```
def sum_items(l): #Don't use "list" for a variable because `list()` is an inbuilt function in Python
    k = 0
    for item in l: #Goes through the actual objects rather than calling them by index
         k += item #k = k + item
    return k

print(sum_items([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

For the first n items, you can just make the list equal to those items

```
def sum_items(start, end, l):
    newList = l[start:end]
    #Do the same on newList


print(sum_items(1, 3, [1, 2, 3, 4])) #Gives back value of 2+3+4 which is 11
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is more like what you were trying to achieve:

```
def sum_items(a_list):
    total = 0
    for item in a_list:
        total += item
    return total

my_list = [2,3,4,5] 

print sum_items(my_list)
```

Tested in Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in sum instead:

```
print(sum(list))
```